# What is wrong with let count=0?

Tags: bash, error-handling, syntax

This appears to me to be valid code:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errtrace

failure()
{
    local lineno=$1
    local msg=$2
    echo "Failed at $lineno: $msg"
    exit
}
trap 'failure ${LINENO} "$BASH_COMMAND"' ERR

let count=0
```

but unfortunately, I get the error, "Failed at 14: let count=0"

What could possibly be wrong with `let count=0`?

**Edit**

Removing `let` prevents the error but I still get an error later when I use `let count++`. I thought both statements were perfectly valid.

Comment: The exit status of `let` is non-zero if the expression evaluates to 0, see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-let). You usually don't need `let` – in this case, `count=0` has the same effect.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but error messages belong on stderr. `echo "Failed at $lineno: $msg" >&2`

Comment: @BenjaminW. count=0 doesn't produce the error but I still get an error later when I use `let count++`. I thought both `let count=0` and `let count++` were perfectly valid as is.

Comment: `count++` is  a *post-increment*; if `count` is currently set to 0, then the value of the expression is still 0, but with a side effect of `count` being set to 1. Compare `++count`, which increments `count` *before* deciding the value of `count`.

Comment: In this instance, I don't care about whether it's pre-increment or post-increment. I just don't want it to throw an error.

Comment: Then don't use `let`; it's *designed* to throw an error when the result of the (last) expression evaluated is 0.

Comment: If you aren't actually doing math, `count=0` has *exactly* the same side effect as `let count=0`; it assigns the value `0` to the name `count`. But it *always* has an exit status of 0, regardless of the value being assigned.

Comment: If you *do* want to do math, you can write `count=$((...))`, and the exit status will still be 0 regardless of the value of the evaluated expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there appears to be no good way to handle errors in bash, considering an error code does not always mean an error. I've found no way to determine whether an error code means there's an error or not. I've found 2 solutions to the problem:

1 ) Pipe to true or use || true.

```
let count=0 | true
let count++ | true

# Or
let count=0 || true
let count++ || true
```

2 ) Turn the error handler behaviour off to suppress the behaviour.

```
failure()
{
    if (( errsOff == 0 )); then
        local fileName=$0
        local lineMo=$1
        local message=$2
        echo "Failed at $lineMo, in file $fileName: $message"
        exit
    fi
}
trap 'failure ${LINENO} "$BASH_COMMAND"' ERR

declare -g errsOff=0

errsOff=1
let count=0
let count++
errsOff=0
```

For functions I write myself, I can avoid the problem by using `echo` to return a value, and by using `return` only for returning an error code.

Answer (score 4):

From the manual:

```
   let arg [arg ...]
          Each arg is an arithmetic expression to be evaluated (see ARITH-
          METIC EVALUATION above).  If the last arg evaluates  to  0,  let
          returns 1; 0 is returned otherwise.
```

Note that `let` is *specifically* for evaluating arithmetic expressions, not arbitrary variable assignments. Arithmetic expressions *include* assignments, for example:

```
$ let "x = 3"
$ echo "$x"
3
```

but you can use any arithmetic expression:

```
$ let "3 + 5"; echo $?
0
$ let "3 - 3"; echo $?
1
```

The exit status is not the *value* of the expression, but an indication of whether the value is 0 or non-zero. The value of an assignment is the value that gets assigned.

Typically, it's safer to write `count=$((...))` rather than `let count=...` if you want an arithmetic expression evaluated, so that you don't have to worry about stray non-zero exit statuses.

`let` is effectively replaced by the arithmetic statement `((...))` in modern `bash`.